# assignment of C++ vector of vector of double = safe?

Tags: c++, vector

Is the assignment below always performed with neither memory leaks nor uninitialized or even unallocated memory?

No cell in the resulting `a` will have the same address as a cell in the resulting `b`?

Would this be the case no matter how many vectors of vectors... of vectors we have?

```
vector<vector<double>> a, b;

// Give a and b random contents: empty, rectangular, ragged, etc.

a = b;
```

Comment: Right. `std::vector` isn't totally broken.

Comment: "no matter how many vectors of vectors of ..." don't do that.  It's not great with one of them - but the moment you have 2 nested you can be pretty sure that your design has taken a wrong turn.

Comment: fair enough, what alternatives should be considered?

Comment: "Copy assignment operator. Replaces the contents with a copy of the contents of other." More information on [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

Comment: curious why all the downvotes?  Is the question not clear enough?  Are basic questions simply frowned upon?  I searched overflow and didn't see this questions posed elsewhere.

Comment: Strange downvote sniping, without a valid reason going on here - shame.

Comment: The c++ community on SO seems to have a tendency to downvote questions that seems obvious to them. I think it's seen as evidence of insufficient research. Unfortunately, while I would assume this information is wildly available, it can be difficult for beginners to come up with the right search terms for problems like these.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree the community could be harsh sometimes, but "research" also takes into account the books/tutorials the OP has gone through which, if any good, teach him the basic terminology.

Comment: @DeiDei I agree with you. But unfortunately, it's shocking how many developers can't properly describe what value semantics mean. It's a concept the current state of education seems to miss constantly, and it seems to me like the keyword here.

Comment: You may want to pass the vector by reference to avoid copying.

Answer (score 4):

All of the memory issues that might arise from dynamic allocation are taken care for you by `std::vector`, `operator=` does exactly what you think it does. If it's good practice is another question..

Answer (score 1):

What a surprise! Nobody sited [exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).

Every piece of code in the standard libray followes the *basic exception safety*. Some operation ensures *strong exception safety* others are noexcept (nothrow guarantee).

For vector copy, the standard does not say much. But I know that libstdc++ and libc++ ensure strong exception safety. So either the operation succeed and all post conditions are ensured, or an exception is thrown and the state of the vector is not changed.

---

When programming, and any sensible c++ coder does it, always ensures that each piece of code ensures the *basic exception safety*. Moreover it is a good idea specify in comments which exception safety ensures each function.

Your question is realy pertinent. Exception safety is what makes container implementation non trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not necessarily best practise, vectors of vectors of vectors are perfectly valid.